# How to edit a javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm new to Javascript and I have an object that printed to console gives this :

```
Object
    mots[4]:"unique"
```

I would like to edit it to get :

```
Object
    mots[4].lettre:"unique"
```

I tried using stringify, split and splice but that didn't work. So what is the 'cleanest' way to do that?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: change to: mots[4]="unique"

Comment: This question is very poor! That could be easily resolve by just doing a little bit of reading!

Answer (score 3):

`mots[4] = { lettre : "unique" }`

or generically..

`mots[i] = { lettre : mots[i] }`

or for each value in the array you can do..

```
mots = mots.map(function(x) { return { lettre : x }; });
```

This will convert every element of the array to be an object with the property lettre with the value of the original element. Learn more about [the map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var mots = ['This', 'answer', 'is', 'very', 'unique'];

console.log('Before:');
console.log(mots);
console.log('mots[4] : ' + mots[4]);

mots = mots.map(function(x) { return { lettre : x }; });

console.log('After:');
console.log(mots);
console.log('mots[4].lettre : ' + mots[4].lettre);
```

Comment: I can't resolve it that way, because the number 4 is variable, let's say it's mots[i] and i want to do that generically

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign to it an object.

```
var a=4;
mots[a]={letter:"unique"};
```

You can access it using `bracket` notation.

```
console.log(mots[a]["lettre"]).
```

```js
var mots=[];
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
  mots[i]=i;
}
a=4;
console.log(mots);
mots[a]={letter:"unique"};
console.log(mots[a]["letter"]);
```